# a bug with if and else if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, codeblocks

I'm making this for my college project, my problem is whenever I put these 3 specific inputs: 98, 95, 96; it will output 96.33333, and it would never output the Equivalent Grade line. Sorry I'm just a beginner, I'm still not familiar to coding jargons. Can anybody help me how I could fix this bug? I would appreciate it so much. Thank you in advanced!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double prelim = 0.0;
    double midterm = 0.0;
    double finals = 0.0;
    double gen = 0.0;
    double equiv = 0.0;

    cout << "Enter Prelim Grade : ";
    cin >> prelim;
    cout << "Enter Midterm Grade : ";
    cin >> midterm;
    cout << "Enter Finals Grade : ";
    cin >> finals;
    cout << endl;

    gen = (prelim + midterm + finals) / 3;

    cout << "Your General Average is: " << gen << endl;

    if (gen <= 100 && gen >= 97)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.0";
    }
    else if (gen <= 96 && gen >= 94)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.25";
    }
    else if (gen <= 93 && gen >= 91)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.50";
    }
    else if (gen <= 90 && gen >= 88)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.75";
    }
    else if (gen <= 87 && gen >= 85)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 2.0";
    }
    else if (gen <= 84 && gen >= 82)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 2.25";
    }
    else if (gen <= 81 && gen >= 79)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 2.50";
    }
    else if (gen <= 78 && gen >= 76)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 2.75";
    }
    else if (gen == 75)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 3.0";
    }
    else if (gen < 75)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 5.0";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! My code is now perfectly working, really much appreciate it

Comment: Rather than commenting with a thanks, upvote the useful answers and accept the best of them. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is a short guide on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the first condition

```
if(gen <= 100 && gen >= 97)
```

nor the second one

```
else if (gen <= 96 && gen >= 94)
```

apply here. Specifically 96.333 is neither `>= 97` nor `<= 96` but in between.

A simple solution would be to round `gen`:

```
gen = std::round(gen);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```cpp
if (gen <= 100 && gen >= 97)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.0";
    }
    else if (gen <= 96 && gen >= 94)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.25";
    }
```

Your checking if it's less than or equal to 100 and greater than or equal to 97. Then your checking if it's less than or equal to 96 or greater than or equal to 94. You don't have any if statement checking between 96 and 97 therefore it won't print anything out. To fix this you could do something like this

```cpp
if (gen <= 100 && gen > 96)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.0";
    }
    else if (gen <= 96 && gen >= 94)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.25";
    }
```

or

```cpp
if (gen <= 100 && gen >= 97)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.0";
    }
    else if (gen < 97 && gen >= 94)
    {
        cout << "Equivalent Grade is: 1.25";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statements you have holes, in your example 98, 96, 95 gen = 96.33 and in your if statements there's: `if (gen <= 100 && gen >= 97)`  where the code will skip this if statement and go into the else branch: `else if (gen <= 96 && gen >= 94)`, where your code will also skip it, it doesn't recognize numbers between 96 and 97.
The solution is you either want to change the if statements or round the number before the if statements, you can do that using the function round(x); where x is the number you want to round, this function is from the library **cmath** (`#include <cmath>`)
For more info about this function i recommend going through this article:
https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cmath/round

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to checking which range a value is inside of is to only have one condition in each `if` branch. That way you're not writing redundant code.

```
if (gen > 100) something_is_wrong();
else if (gen >= 97) do_something_with_top_range();
else if (gen >= 94) do_something_with_next_range();
... // et cetera
```

In `else if (gen >=94)` there's no need to test whether `gen` is less than 97; the code won't reach that `else if` statement if `gen` is above that range, because the preceding `else if` handled that case.